# Converting Between Hibernate Collections and My Own Collections

Tags: java, hibernate

I have set up Hibernate to give me a `Set<Integer>` which I convert internally to and from a `Set<MyObjectType>` (`MyObjectType` can be represented by a single integer).  That is to say, When Hibernate calls my `void setMyObjectTypeCollection(Set<Integer> theSet)` method I iterate through all the elements in `theSet` and convert them to `MyObjectType`.  When Hibernate calls my `Set<MyObjectType> getMyObjectTypeCollection()` I allocate a new HashSet and convert `MyObjectType`s to `Integer`s.

The problem is that every time I call `commit`, Hibernate deletes everything in the collection and then re-inserts it regardless of whether any element of the collection has changed or even that the collection itself has changed.

While I don't technically consider this a bug, I am afraid that deleting and inserting many rows very often will cause the database to perform unnecessarily slowly.

Is there a way to get Hibernate to recognize that even though I have allocated and returned a different instance of the collection, that the collection actually contains all the items it used to and that there is no need to delete and reinsert them all?

Comment: Why was the design decision made to use Integers in lieu of your actual class?

This isn't a bug, but the functionality of Hibernate, as you are creating new objects that are not in a persistent context and putting them into a persistent context.  The deleting does not make sense, but it is hard to tell without specific code.

Showing some of your code/mapping might help with understanding your problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve your goal would be to use a [UserType](http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Hibernate/3.2.4.sp01.cp03/api/hibernate-core/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html). Basically it lets you handle the conversion from SQL to your own objects (back and forth).

You can see an example on how to use it [here](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/UserTypeforpersistingaTypesafeEnumerationwithaVARCHARcolumn).